# Generating JSON - Malformed UTF-8 Characters consuming WHMCS API

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm using CURL to consume WHMCS API and when I try to parse the response I'm getting this error:

> **Error generating JSON encoded response: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded**

I've tried using `json_encode($data, true)` and then decode it

```
public static function execute($action, $options, $filters = [])
{

    $domain = $options['domain'] . '/includes/api.php';

    $arr = array(
        'identifier' => $options['identifier'],
        'secret' => $options['secret'],
        'action' => $action,
        'responsetype' => 'json'
    );

    $arr = array_merge($arr, $filters);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $domain);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($arr));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($response);
}
```

Comment: We can't possibly answer this with the information you've given us. Where is the error coming from? If it's your code, what line in the code? Why are you using `utf8_decode`?

Comment: UTF8 does not need to be "decoded" and those functions are stupidly named. Don't use them.

Comment: take a look at github.com/neitanod/forceutf8 , run this on your data before using json_encode. Is the error coming from the API or your code?

Comment: It was without `utf8_decode` before, also Im not encoding the JSON. Im consuming WHMCS API and it returns valid JSON. I can parse every other response except when I request to `getClientsProducts`

Comment: @GhoSTBG for me same problem. Only problems with getClientsProducts. Increible API.